# MongoDB $group command in c++

Tags: c++, mongodb, qt, aggregation-framework

I have problems getting the **$group** command of mongodb to work in c++ (Qt)

The example code of the documentation works as expected and returns results:

```js
db.article.aggregate(
    { "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$author",
        "docsPerAuthor" : { "$sum" : 1 }
    }}
);`
```

The translation to c++ however returns an empty result set but no error:

```
QString queryCommand =  "{ group : {"
                          "_id : \"$author\", "
                          "docsPerAuthor : {$sum : 1} "
                        "}}";

BSONObj bson_query_result = m_mongoConnection.findOne("data.collection",
                fromjson(queryCommand.toStdString().c_str()));


std::cout << "Output: " << bson_query_result.toString() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregation is invoked through the "runCommand" method which takes the database name and a  BSONObj containing the command and collection, plus the actual pipeline which is an array. The final argument is the response object. Full [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_connection.html#a3f0d7365e8968f66728cef668869d96a).

Assuming you have a DBClientConnection m_mongoConnection and using the "test" database:

```
 BSONObj res;

 BSONArray pipeline = BSON_ARRAY( 
     BSON( "$group" << 
         BSON( "_id" << "$author" ) << 
         BSON( "docsPerAuthor" <<
             BSON( "$sum" << 1 )
         )
     )
 );

 m_mongoConnection.runCommand( 
     "test", BSON( 
        "aggregate" << "article" << "pipeline" << pipeline 
     ), 
     res 
 );

 cout << res.toString() << endl
```

Depending on your personal tastes for how to construct the BSON arguments.

Comment: Hello,thank you for the advice, it was very useful, but I think that your code has a little mistake: Where is  BSONArray pipeline = BSON_ARRAY( 
     BSON( "$group" << 
         BSON( "_id" << "$author" ) << 
         BSON( "docsPerAuthor" <<
             BSON( "$sum" << 1 )
         )
     )
 ); should be BSONArray pipeline = BSON_ARRAY( 
     BSON( "$group" << 
         BSON( "_id" << "$author" << "docsPerAuthor" <<
             BSON( "$sum" << 1 )
         )
     )
 );